# Spring MVC Module can't reach dependencies in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I've got a multi-module maven project, and one of the module is a spring mvc project. Intellij is telling me that it can't find the dependencies... The dependencies are other modules in the same project, and I'm getting this error:

`cannot access blah.de.blah`

Interestingly, maven successfully builds the module, so I'm not sure why intellij has a problem. I've tried compiling the project from Intellij.

Comment: IntelliJ is complaining about the Spring @autowired etc to the other Spring resources?

Comment: ...no it's happy with the dependencies of spring itself...

Comment: I don't know intellij to give you an answer but when that happens on eclipse it means that it is using an embedded version of maven (a plugin) therefore it is not reading the repository properly. Also Eclipse have a functionality which is "update maven project" maybe intellij also have this feature. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

...I've not clue why but this is what happened:

Intellij had created a directory named 'a.b.c' instead of nesting the packages. I fixed that, re-marked the source directories as sources/tests etc, and the problem went away.